# Timeout ошибка ожидания ответа сервера ajax

Tags: ajax, reactjs, golang

Я использую ajax запросы в JS, они идут в приложение на Go, Go идет в sql и всё это собирается обратно. Некоторые запросы получаются долгими и всё просто отваливается по таймеру через минуту. Я в разработке совсем недавно, знаю что всё собирается на докере и ошибку конкретно выдает Nginx. 
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Что делать? 
Видела просто на сайтах вылазит окошко типа "Не отвечает, подождать?" - как это реализовать?

Comment: Во-первых, увеличивайте ваши таймеры. Во-вторых, непонятно, что мешает вам нарисовать окошко при отправке ajax-запроса

Answer (score 0):

Во первых мало инфы: нужны логи, скрины ошибки, примеры Ваших конфигов.
Во вторых надо не алерт с ожиданием разрабытвать, а искать и оптимизировать запросы, которые долго выполняются.

Сделайте профилирование кода, который долго выполняется и думаю найдете код который долго выполняется.